# Dividing a binary mask to subregions

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, post-processing

I have a neural network (NN) that segments an object and predicts a binary mask:
[image]

I want to divide this binary mask into further subregions:
tip, first third, center, left, right, root

which would result in something like this:
[image]

**Solution ideas**

(A)
One could introduce a semantic segmentation task to solve the dividing with NN, but preparing the labels for this would be a high effort. Additionally, the subregions are stuck together in order, for example, left-center-right which the NN does not assume.

(B)
I am thinking of a binary-mask post-processing algorithm that could do this subregioning. For example, if we could transform the mask to be a square, we could apply a handcrafted template for it and then transform it back into the mask shape. This could result in adequate subregioning, but I have no clue whether it is possible or how could it be implemented.

Any different ideas for solving this problem? Or some tip on how could be (B) done?

Comment: _that's a **tongue**_, right? https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/does-the-tongue-have-different-taste-zones

Comment: yes, you are right, but this fact does not contributes to the core of the problem :)

Comment: I too think it's feasible to train a neural network for semantic segmentation (multi-label) towards this purpose.

Comment: "semantic segmentation for parts" should "work", even if these parts lack visual features. the network would learn to distribute the labeling of those parts like a human would, within the outline of the tongue.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Semantic Segmentation for Parts:**
   I do not think this will work, even if you obtain labeling for the different parts. Since the partitioning into the different regions is *functional* and not *visual*, the different parts do not have identifying *visual* features. Moreover, any NN you train does not have access to *functional* information, only visual and therefore there's not much for a NN to learn here.
2. **Post Processing:**
   Your idea of post-processing the mask based on its *geometry* might be a good proxy for the lack of *functional* information. What you can do is:

- Find the center of mass of the masked region.
- Find the major axis of the mask.

  This will give you a "canonical" projection to a *circle* (rather than a square). you can then have a circular "atlas" dividing the circle into the different regions and project back the atlas to the mask via the "canonical" circular mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you please elaborate on the process of canonical projection to a circle? Or could you please refer to sources from where I can gather the necessary information for implementation?